# C++ SFML Sprite not drawing, however no errors occur

Tags: c++, class, sfml

I've been trying to make a sprite display in C++ SFML but with the use of classes. However, when I compile and run the program, nothing appears: there are no errors either.

(The only thing that happens in main is that a 'Game' object is created)

**Game.h**

```
    #ifndef GAME_H
    #define GAME_H
    #include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
    #include "Player.h"
    
    
    class Game
    {
        public:
            Game();
        private:
            //Variables
            sf::RenderWindow _mainWindow;
            enum _gameState { Playing, Paused, Splash, Menu };
    
            //Methods
            void gameLoop();
    };
    
    #endif // GAME_H
```

**Game.cpp**

```
#include "Game.h"
#include "Player.h"

Game::Game() {

    //Variables
    _mainWindow.create(sf::VideoMode(960, 640), "Game", sf::Style::Titlebar | sf::Style::Close);
    _mainWindow.setFramerateLimit(60);

   //Start Game Loop
    gameLoop();

}

void Game::gameLoop() {

    Player player;

    while(_mainWindow.isOpen()) {

        sf::Event ev;
        while(_mainWindow.pollEvent(ev)) {
            if(ev.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                _mainWindow.close();
            if(ev.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed) {
                if(ev.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Escape)
                    _mainWindow.close();
            }
        }


        //Draw Stuff
        _mainWindow.clear(sf::Color::White);
        player.drawSprite(_mainWindow);
        _mainWindow.display();

    }

}
```

**Player.h**

```
#ifndef PLAYER_H
#define PLAYER_H
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>


class Player
{
    public:
        Player();
        void drawSprite(sf::RenderWindow& window);
    private:
        bool loadSprite();
        sf::Texture _playerTexture;
        sf::Sprite _playerSprite;
};

#endif // PLAYER_H
```

**Player.cpp**

```
#include "Player.h"
#include "Game.h"


Player::Player()
{
    if(!Player::loadSprite()){
        return;
    }
}

bool Player::loadSprite() {

    sf::Texture _playerTexture;
    if(!_playerTexture.loadFromFile("img/darkguy.png", sf::IntRect(32,32,32,32))) {
        std::cout << "Failed to load player image" << std::endl;
        return false;
    } else {
        sf::Sprite _playerSprite;
        _playerSprite.setTexture(_playerTexture);
    }

    return true;
}

void Player::drawSprite(sf::RenderWindow& window) {

    //sprite.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(10, 10, 32, 32));
    window.draw(_playerSprite);
    std::cout << "Sprite Drawn Successfully" << std::endl;

}
```

Comment: the `if` in your `Player` constructor is useless, just call `loadSprite` without the `if`

Answer (score 3):

You are declaring a new, local _playerSprite here:

```
} else {
    sf::Sprite _playerSprite;
    _playerSprite.setTexture(_playerTexture);
}
```

instead, use the existing class member:

```
} else {
    _playerSprite.setTexture(_playerTexture);
}
```

You may want to drop the first line from this code as well, same issue:

```
bool Player::loadSprite() 
{
    sf::Texture _playerTexture; // <--- local redeclaration
```

Comment: Thanks for spotting that mistake, but still no sprite displaying - any guesses? EDIT: thanks, after changing the texture it works - thanks a lot :P

Answer (score 1):

From my memories: the texture must be a member of your class; it must exist while you are using it. In your code, _playerTexture is destroyed at the end of loadSprite(). Same problem for _playerSprite.

---

**Edit:**

You don't have to re-declare the member of your class in your methods :

```
bool Player::loadSprite() {
    sf::Texture _playerTexture;
    if(!_playerTexture.loadFromFile("img/darkguy.png", sf::IntRect(32,32,32,32))) {
        std::cout << "Failed to load player image" << std::endl;
        return false;
    } else {
        sf::Sprite _playerSprite;
        _playerSprite.setTexture(_playerTexture);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Should be:

```
bool Player::loadSprite() {
    if(!_playerTexture.loadFromFile("img/darkguy.png", sf::IntRect(32,32,32,32))) {
        std::cout << "Failed to load player image" << std::endl;
        return false;
    } else {
        _playerSprite.setTexture(_playerTexture);
    }
    return true;
}
```

(PS: Your code doesn't respect the SRP (Single Responsability Principle), Player doesn't have to display itself.)

Comment: I feel like I had to note: SRP is a matter of definition. If you feel you must have one point which renders everything, then that's one point of view. But if you feel every class should render itself as to keep everything related to this class in that class, then that's another point of view. I do agree though that op here did something non-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

you are drawing but not displaying the sprite for that do this

```
void Player::drawSprite(sf::RenderWindow& window) {

//sprite.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(10, 10, 32, 32));
window.draw(_playerSprite);
std::cout << "Sprite Drawn Successfully" << std::endl;
//this is the display function

window.display()
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).